# How To Set Up A Password Probability Problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Kain has to make a 7-character password.  For each scenario, calculate the total possible outcomes.

All characters must be upper-case letters.  All five vowels (A,E,I,O,U) must be used. No letter may be used more than once.

Could someone show me how to go about setting this one up? All of the other problems I have done only have one condition that has to be met, and I am unsure on how to do this one that has two.

Comment: Fix a permutation of the vowels, now choose $5$ slots in which to place them.  Then populate the remaining two slots with distinct consonants.

Comment: So would it simply be 5*4*3*2*1*21*20 = 50,400

Comment: no, you have 21*20 to pick the 2 letters, and then 7*6*5*...*1 to change their order

Comment: It's $5!$ for the permutation, $\binom {7}5$ for the vowel placement, and then $21\times 20$ to place consonants.

Comment: I disagree, you have to choose your 7 letters, 5 of them are already chosen, for 2 more there is 21*20 solutions. Now you can permute those 7 letters in 7! ways, so total=21*20*7*6*5*4*3*2*1=2116800

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov: You have provided solution with reasoning. Why don't you post it as an answer instead of keeping it as a comment? No point in having questions remaining artificially unanswered.

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov: I think calculating $21\cdot 20$ respects an ordering of consonants. When multiplying with $7\cdot6\cdots 1$ it is done a second time.

Comment: Yes, my fault, Byron answered it well, I knew I was being wrong at something so I didn't write answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We have to place $5$ vowels at $7$ positions whereby the order of vowels matter.

  So, we can select positions for the vowels in $\binom{7}{5}$ ways and since the order matters each selection gives $5!$ different configurations.
- Assuming an alphabet with $26$ characters, two positions are left for $26-5=21$ characters, which can be placed in $21\cdot 20$ different ways.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> 5!\binom{7}{5}\cdot 21\cdot 20=1058400
> \end{align*}
>   different possibilities to choose a valid password.

Answer (score 1):

- Choose two consonants: $21\choose 2$ ways
- Order the seven distinct letters: $7!$ ways

The answer is ${21\choose 2}\cdot 7!=1058400.$